# How to use two java bean to display data in a jsp

Tags: spring, jsp, jstl

I want to display user's detail in a jsp. user's email, name is in one bean. which i am getting in a PagedListHolder. now i need date too which is in another bean . how can i add this date to PagedListHolder. i am using spring mvc framework

```
public String listUsers(Map<String, Object> map, @RequestParam(value="p", required=false) Integer p) {
        PagedListHolder pagedListHolder = new PagedListHolder(usersService.listUsers());
        map.put("date11", userActivity.getLastSeen_time());
        int page = p;
        pagedListHolder.setPage(page);
        int pageSize = 2;
        pagedListHolder.setPageSize(pageSize);
        map.put("pagedListHolder", pagedListHolder);
        System.out.println(":::::::::");
        return "userListView";
    }
```

in jsp i am using it as

```
<c:forEach items="${pagedListHolder.pageList}"  var="user">
                <tr onmouseover="ChangeColor(this, true);" onmouseout="ChangeColor(this, false);" onclick="DoNav('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/secure/detailUserView');">
                    <td>${user.name}</td>
                    <td>${user.email}</td>
                    <td>`DATE`</td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
```

in jsp in place of DATE i need to display date which is in date bean

Answer (score 0):

If the pagedListHolder stored as `"pagedListHolder"` in the map is available using `${pagedListHolder}`, then the date, stored as `"date11"` in the map, must also be available using `${date11}`.

You can format it using `<fmt:formatDate value="{date11}"/>`.